# Calculate Kinect X,Y,Z position when a zoom lens is applied

Tags: c#, zooming, kinect

I am working on a college project using two kinect sensors. We are taking the X and Z coordinates from both kinects and converting them into "real world" X and Z coordinates with an offset and some basic math. Everything works great without the zoom lens but when the zoom lens is added the coordinate system get's distorted.

We are using this product [http://www.amazon.com/Zoom-Kinect-Xbox-360/dp/B0050SYS5A](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0050SYS5A)

We seem to be going from a 57 degree view to a 113 degree view when switching the to the zoom lens. What would be a good way of trying to calculate this change in the coordinate system. How can we convert these distorted X and Z coordinates to the "real world" coordinates.

The sensors are places next to each other, at a 0 degree angle, looking at the same wall with some of their view fields overlapping. The overlap get's greater with the zoom lenses.

Thanks for any answers or ideas!

Comment: Technically, widening the angle of view can't be considered zoom.
You'll need to figure out a matrix describing the difference between the regular kinect and the kinect with the lens and apply the matrix to your data before doing any actual math with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can take pictures via the kinect, you should be able to use a checkerboard pattern and camera calibration tool (e.g. [GML calibration toolbox](http://graphics.cs.msu.ru/en/node/909)) to deduce the camera parameters/distortion of each lens system.

You should then be able to transform the data from each camera and its respective lens system to world coordinates.

If your measurements of the relative orientation and position of the cameras (and math) are correct the coordinates should roughly agree.